# Solving endless loop in verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog

I'm having some problems with for-loop statement in verilog.

```
reg [31:0] i;

initial begin
  for (i=2; i > 0; i = i - 1) begin
    $display ("%d\n", i);
  end
end
```

This code runs without any problem, but if I change the middle condition to i >= 0, the program runs repeatedly without no hope of stopping.

I don't understand why this happen!

PS: The full code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/3LX0Mkg0

Comment: Is `i` being interpreted as an unsigned number? In this case, `0-1=2^32-1 > 0` which would explain the infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eric gave the answer in a comment, so I am copying it here as an answer:

In verilog `reg [31:0] i;` is interpreted as an unsigned number. Therefore `i >= 0` will always be true.  In order to define `i` as signed you have to define it like this: `reg signed [31:0] i;`

While we are talking about signed numbers in verilog I want to point out a major gotcha: if you do a part select of a signed number (like `i[15:0]`) the result is unsigned. This is the case even if you select all of the bits like `i[31:0]`.  You can fix this using the `$signed` task like this: `$signed(i[15:0])`